# Generated Image for Tile with wrong Color

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to update the app tile with a generated Image. I get no errors but the image is just black now instead of this color: 'Color.FromArgb( 255, 0, 100, 50 )'. Any Idea why?

```
//This have to be the Image, just a colored squer for the beginning
var TestTile = new Grid()
                {
                    Background          = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb( 255, 0, 100, 50 ) ),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment   = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                    Height              = 336,
                    Width               = 336,
                    Margin              = new Thickness( 0, 12, 0, 0 ),
                };

                //generation the image and save it within isoStorage
                using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!store.DirectoryExists("shared/shellcontent"))
                    {
                        store.CreateDirectory("shared/shellcontent");
                    }  
                    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
                    bitmap.Render(TestTile, new TranslateTransform());
                    var stream = store.CreateFile("/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg");
                    bitmap.Invalidate();
                    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 366, 336, 0, 100);
                    stream.Close();
                }

                // Tile Update
                ShellTile PinnedTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
                FlipTileData UpdatedTileData = new FlipTileData
                {

                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), 

                };
                PinnedTile.Update(UpdatedTileData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, here is how I save tile images.

1. I always use Shared\ShellContent\ for the location. Not sure if case matters (it shouldn't)
2. I always call Measure, then Arrange on the UIElement before sending it to the WriteableBitmap
3. Use UriKind.Absolute for the background uri

Try to save your image like such:

```
string fileName = @"Shared\ShellContent\Tile.jpg";
Grid someElement = new Grid() 
{
    // Add Stuff
}
someElement.Measure(new Size(width, height));
someElement.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,width, height));
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(someElement, null);

using(var stream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100);
}

Uri uri = new Uri("isostore:/" + fileName, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: Ok I will try to use a rect to set a color to the background

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "ms-appdata" URI scheme to access the file instead. The path to your image would then be as follows:

```
BackgroundImage = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

That's what I use to set the tile image in one of my apps and it works as expected.

Refer to the section "Local folder URI schemes" in the Data for Windows Phone article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary

Comment: Sorry I have the problem already - but now I have an other - I have updated my post